# Реализация браузера с помощью компонента WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Написал простой браузер на C#, но он не работает, хотя должен! Помогите, пожалуйста. Все нужные компоненты подключены.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ololo
{

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        string author = "johniek_comp";
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "developed by "+author;
        }
        void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            label2.Text = "загрузка...";
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://"+textBox1.Text); 
        }

        void Label2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = "";
        }
     }
}
```

А как сделать так, чтобы в то что вводишь в text.Box1 загружалось? как я в первом посте указал

Comment: @johniek_comp  очевидно же. Смотри мое сообщение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что метод [WebBrowser.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352.aspx) принимает в качестве параметра объект класса [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), а не простую строку.
Нужно как-то так:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://"+ textBox1.Text));
```